# How to compile python to dll/so library?

Tags: python

I intend to use php to develop an object detection but i have not yet found any source code in google. I have found a source code(Image AI) which is developed by python.

Can i compile the ImageAI into dll/so library? So that i can use in php.

I am a newbie in programming, so hope someone can answer my question.(This is my first time use stack overflow to ask question, so if mine question not fulfill the requirement, please forgive me.)

Below is the link of Image AI :
https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI

I am using windows 7,wamp3.1.7,php7.2.14